# Google Test and Google Mock do not work with extern global variables

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

I am trying to use `google test` and `google mock` to test my simple C++ class. My mock class looks like this:

```
#pragma once

#include "base_classes/_HardwareSerial.h"
#include "gmock/gmock.h"

class HardwareSerial : public _HardwareSerial
{
public:
    HardwareSerial() = default;
    MOCK_METHOD(void, begin, (unsigned long baud_rate), (override));
    MOCK_METHOD(void, end, (), (override));
    MOCK_METHOD(void, print, (const __FlashStringHelper *in_flash_str), (override));
    MOCK_METHOD(void, print, (const char *str), (override));
};

extern HardwareSerial Serial;
```

Now I make use of this mock class in my test cpp file:

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <gmock/gmock.h>
#include "HardwareSerial.h"

using ::testing::_;

HardwareSerial Serial; // <<< Putting this here does NOT work. The test passes whatever if the function has never been called called 10000 times. The test just passes.. This is the problem I have.

HardwareSerial AnotherNewSerial; // <<< Does NOT work.

class Test_Class: public ::testing::Test
{
protected:
    HardwareSerial Serial; // <<< Putting this here makes the test working, but of course if anything relies on the global extern variable will cause compilation error.
    HardwareSerial AnotherNewSerial; // <<< Works.

    void SetUp() override
    {
    }

    void TearDown() override
    {
    }
};

TEST_F(Test_Class, MYTEST)
{
    EXPECT_CALL(Serial, begin(_))
        .Times(10);
}
```

Defining the external `HardwareSerial Serial` variable in the global area in my test causes that the test passes whatever I do with this variable. So my `EXPECT_CALL` just does not cause the test to fail without caring if the method `begin` was called or not. It just always passes!

However, moving the declaration into the class makes the test work as expected. However, I cannot rely on this because I have other components rely on this global extern variable. And it is very interesting to know what is going on here and how I can fix this?

#### UPDATE:

It seems to have nothing to do with `extern`, declaring a new variable of type `HardwareSerial` in the global area causes exactly the same problem, and moving it into the classes removes the problem.

Comment: I did not find it officially anywhere, but it seems that instantiating an instance of type `Google Mocks` before google test/mock is initialized somehow does not work. This is the reason apparently why I have the problem mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

TL,DR: tend to create mock objects as test case's members.

Long explanation:

Please see [Google Mock intro here](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/gmock_for_dummies.md#using-mocks-in-tests) regarding how to use them, especially last point:

> When a mock is **destructed**, gMock will automatically check whether all
> expectations on it have been satisfied.

(bold by me). The key thing is that the `EXPECT_CALL`s are evaluated against the  actual calls when the mock object is destructed (this is a common thing in C++ to depend on RAII). Global object like that is destructed when the program's `main` method exits, so you won't see any errors after the test case ends. When the mock object is defined in the test suite, it will be created at the beginning of the test and destructed when the test ends (to be precise: mock is constructed in test case's ctor and is destructed when the test case's dtor is called. This is done for each test case in a given test suite if you use `TEST_F`).